How to udpate a value in a nested and partly flattened object with jq?
I need to override the property version with the value of image. The problem is, that the json document can have several forms, whereby parts of the nesting can be flattened:
Example Document 1
{
  "modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired.modules.event-bridge-redis": {
        "settings": {
          "image": "redis:6.2.7",
          "createOptions": ""
        },
        "type": "docker",
        "status": "running",
        "restartPolicy": "always",
        "version": "1.0"
      },
      "properties.desired.modules.event-bridge-metrics": {
        "settings": {
          "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-metrics-collector:1.19",
          "createOptions": ""
        },
        "type": "docker",
        "version": "1.0",
        "status": "running",
        "restartPolicy": "always"
      }
    },
    "$edgeHub": {
    }
  }
}

Example document 2
{
  "modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired.modules": {
        "event-bridge-redis": {
          "settings": {
            "image": "redis:6.2.7",
            "createOptions": ""
          },
          "type": "docker",
          "status": "running",
          "restartPolicy": "always",
          "version": "1.0"
        },
        "event-bridge-metrics": {
          "settings": {
            "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-metrics-collector:1.19",
            "createOptions": ""
          },
          "type": "docker",
          "version": "1.0",
          "status": "running",
          "restartPolicy": "always"
        }
      }
    },
    "$edgeHub": {
    }
  }
}

Expected output of Example Document 1
{
  "modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired.modules.event-bridge-redis": {
        "settings": {
          "image": "redis:6.2.7",
          "createOptions": ""
        },
        "type": "docker",
        "status": "running",
        "restartPolicy": "always",
        "version": "redis:6.2.7"
      },
      "properties.desired.modules.event-bridge-metrics": {
        "settings": {
          "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-metrics-collector:1.19",
          "createOptions": ""
        },
        "type": "docker",
        "version": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-metrics-collector:1.19",
        "status": "running",
        "restartPolicy": "always"
      }
    },
    "$edgeHub": {
    }
  }
}

Expected output of Example document 2
{
  "modulesContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired.modules": {
        "event-bridge-redis": {
          "settings": {
            "image": "redis:6.2.7",
            "createOptions": ""
          },
          "type": "docker",
          "status": "running",
          "restartPolicy": "always",
          "version": "redis:6.2.7"
        },
        "event-bridge-metrics": {
          "settings": {
            "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-metrics-collector:1.19",
            "createOptions": ""
          },
          "type": "docker",
          "version": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-metrics-collector:1.19",
          "status": "running",
          "restartPolicy": "always"
        }
      }
    },
    "$edgeHub": {
    }
  }
}

Is it possible to define a single jq query, which can handle several forms of nesting (from a flat form to a nested form) and so, that the form of the input is also preserved in the output?

You can use walk to traverse the document, and update |= matching nodes (e.g. objects that have a version key) using a given filter (e.g. assigning the value of .settings.image to .version):
walk(select(type == "object" and has("version")) |= (.version = .settings.image))

Demo

This is exactly what I was looking for. A very clever solution.

Or: walk((objects | select(has("version"))) |= (.version = .settings.image))

Or: (.. | objects | select(has("version"))) |= (.version = .settings.image)

Or: walk(objects |= if has("version") then .version = .settings.image end) Countless possibilities…
